# If $\|Df\|<M$ in a disk, then $M$ is a Lipschitz constant

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Some notes on multi-variable calculus I was reading, they quote a "standard result":

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is such that $\| f'(x)\|
>  \leq M$ for $x\in D$, where $D$ is a closed ball. Then for points $x,
>  x+h \in D$, we have $$|f(x+h)-f(x)| \leq M |h|.$$

The way I can think of to prove this is to take a polygonal path from $x$ to $x+h$ whose length is very close to $h$, and where each linear step is parallel to one of the axes. Then we can use the mean value theorem on each little step. Is that the way you would prove it, or am I missing something totally obvious?

Comment: A closed ball is convex. You can use a straight-line path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prove it using the convexity of $D$. Define $\gamma: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $\gamma(t) = x+th$. Note that $\gamma(0) = x$, $\gamma(1) = x+h$, and $\gamma'(t) = h$. The composition $f\circ \gamma$ has derivative:
$$(f\circ \gamma)'(t) = f'(\gamma(t))\,\gamma'(t)$$
(which is shown via a simple application of multivariable chain rule). By the FTC,
$$f(x+h) - f(x) = \int_0^1 f'(\gamma(t))\,\gamma'(t)\,\textrm{d}t.$$
If you take norms and apply a few basic properties of integrals, you should be able to finish the proof from there.

Comment: I notice that your method requires that $f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$ be integrable (for instance, that $f'$ is continuous). It seems that the way I mention in the question only uses the mean value theorem, and so does not have that requirement. Would you agree?

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct. In most applications of this result you'll have $f\in C^1$ (continuous derivative), but you can show the inequality with your method too. If you'd like, I can edit my answer to include a formal writeup with your method, or are you good?

Comment: No thanks, I think I'm good. Just wanted to keep track that the two ways used different hypotheses. I think it's helpful to develop that intuition, how methods are essentially different, and what they assume is one signature of that.